# Data grabbing that changes constantly

Tags: c#, web, real-time

In my app (C#) I have a WebBrowser that logins automatically to a site, from there I want to take my data and display it in a textBox. How can I do this because when I get the source code I cant find any sellPrice and in DOM Explorer doesn't have any id. Maybe it is because the data changes constantly ?

[image]

Comment: It's DOM. even if the relevant elements don't have set IDs, they're highly likely to show up near/under other fixed elemtns which DO have ids..

Comment: And how could I get that data ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at **HTMLAgilityPack solution**. It is HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM. You can [download](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) it from here.

I hope, it might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking all day long on how to use HAP on my situation, but with no luck :( I've tried examples, sample codes, youtube videos but nothig seems to work.. So please if you can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: Okay, then go though this link - [How to use html agility pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack). I m sure it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data like:

```
HtmlElement he = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbox_sell_price");
```